# How to create deb package from Windows applications?

Tags: windows, wine, packaging, debian

I want to make a deb file from a Windows application which will be run with wine. how do I make it?

As an example, I use Ubuntu Christian Edition and I find the application Virtual Rosary  is installed by default.

My plan: my application will be put in the folder `/opt/*application-name*`, and for the 'launcher.desktop', the Exec argument will bi filled with :

> Exec= wine /opt/*application-name*/ *application-name*.exe

Comment: You don't need to obfuscate "Windows".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can make that happen, but it would be a bit hackish. Fine for personal use, but it would never get accepted into Ubuntu proper.

I'm not sure about your level of knowledge about debian packaging, but giving a whole packaging tutorial is out of scope for this. If you need further information, the [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide) is a good place to start, and of course there is always the [Debian New Maintainer's Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/index.en.html#contents).

Essentially all you need to do is use `dh_install` to drop the files in the right place. So something like this in you `debian/my_package_name.install` file:

```
application-name.exe          /opt/application-name/
application-name.desktop      /usr/share/applications/
```

Comment: hmm, thanks, I'will try it. And this is only for my personal use.

Answer (score 3):

This is something I've personally experimented with a few times, and even made proof of concept packages.  There are also a few ad-hoc packages in the archive such as pq (Progress Quest), although none of them are particularly complicated.

I suggest you follow the specification here: https://blueprints.edge.launchpad.net/software-center/+spec/other-n-wine-software-center  -- At the Developer Summit this month I hope to standardize the way we do this, or even develop a tool to do so, as I expect to have an awful lot of Windows packages in the medium term.